# font-weight is ignored for &cap; (∩)

Tags: html, css, special-characters, styling

I'm using the `&cap;` or 'intersection' symbol (∩) on a web page. I noticed, that Firefox and Chromium don't respect the `font-weight` property for it. Changing the `font-family` didn't help either. I'm using Linux Mint 17.1.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3a9rf2os/) to test it.

A friend of mine also tested it on a mac using Firefox (same result) and Chrome (where `&cap;` and `&cup` ignored the `font-weight`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `&bigcup; &bigcap;`
This should work in chrome and firefox I guess.

https://jsfiddle.net/znyrjp9r/